# Update Stylesheet of an existing Excel file using openXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, sax, openxml-sdk

I am trying to copy an Excel workbook with 4 worksheets (tabs) where 1 worksheet is macro enabled with many formulas using the OpenXML SAX approach as I have lot of data for each sheet.

If I copy the file and and start writing into the worksheets, it starts writing from the 1st line and the headers are being deleted. So I tried copying just the macro-enabled sheet and add other sheets later and add styles to headers.

When I try doing it, the system give an error saying only one style sheet is allowed. `Only one instance of the type is allowed for this parent.`

How can I access the existing stylesheet and add more styling into it for other tabs?

Comment: Where does it say `one style sheet is allowed`?  Why are you assuming the error has something to do with the style sheet?  **Have you tried Googling the exact error?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only one instance of the type is allowed for this parent, but drawing part is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836903/only-one-instance-of-the-type-is-allowed-for-this-parent-but-drawing-part-is-nu)